# Consider $\{(−1)^n + 1/n : n \in \Bbb N\setminus \{0\}\}\subset \Bbb R$. Is this set open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Consider $\{(−1)^n + 1/n : n \in \Bbb N\setminus \{0\}\}\subset \Bbb R$. Is this set open or closed?

As this is a union of discrete points, it should be closed but in the set limit of convergent sequence $1+\frac{1}{2n}$, which is $1$, does not belong to this set, so is this set open, closed or neither of the two?

Comment: You have a valid argument that the set is not closed. Now, is it open?

Comment: There is no rule that a set of discrete points is necessarily closed. A set consisting of a _single_ point is closed, but closedness is not preserved by taking arbitrary unions.

Comment: complement of set of discrete points will be union of open sets so it should be closed as its complement is open i think

Comment: x @njjw, no -- the complement of a union of singletons will be an _intersection_ of open sets, and openness is not preserved by arbitrary intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n=1$ the term is $0,$ yet the set doesn't contain any open interval around $0.$ So the set is not open. You already showed it isn't closed.

Comment: but why my first argument that this set is closed is wrong as it is a defination of closed set

Comment: Your argument produced a point, namely $1,$ which is a limit point of the set but not a member of the set. That means the set is not closed, since a closed set is one which contains all of its limit points. So what you actually showed in your argument is that the set is *not* closed.